# Composer: How to Free up huge amounts of disk space used by composer (gigs)?

Tags: composer-php, space, disk, temporary, tmp

I wanted to know what is taking up so much disk space on my vps and noticed that /tmp-composer and /.composer folders at the root of my account are taking up a lot of disk space. /tmp-composer alone is taking up over 3 gigs.

I've searched for tmp-composer but didnt bring up any a commands or results about what it is and how important. Can I delete the contents of this folder without repercussions? Is there a composer command to empty this folder.

Comment: Does `composer clear-cache` helps?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It helped clear one of the composer cache folders but not the tmp-composer folder .